# Encrypt the string using Angularjs 2 Cryptojs AES CBC algorithm

Tags: angularjs

How do i encrypt the string using Cryptojs AES CBC Algorithm.

I am using the following code to encrypt but the out put is coming different way, expected output: **LiGULkdU27NUgFBDm4qYRw==**

```
  let key = "hUbAwRUYA190pkUpqgTvfg==";
  let iv = key.substring(0,16);
  let string = "1111";               

  let encrypted_upin = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key,
  {
      //keySize: 128 / 8,
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }).toString();

  console.log(encrypted_upin);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as AngularJS 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
var IVstring = CryptoJS.lib.ByteArray(your IV bytearray).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var keystring = CryptoJS.lib.ByteArray(your KEY bytearray).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var text = 'texttobeencrypted';
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(keystring);
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(IVstring);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, {iv: iv});
console.log(encrypted.toString());
```

Script links: Add CryptJS, AES and https://greasyfork.org/scripts/6696-cryptojs-lib-bytearray/code/CryptoJSlibByteArray.js